# Where is the ZFS project for the Mac located as of 2010?

Tags: mac, zfs

Where is the ZFS project for the Mac located as of 2010? The Mac Forge project appears to have closed down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The majority of the team has left since the oft-cited ZFS project at macosxforge.org shut down.

Check [here](http://groups.google.com/group/zfs-macos) for the "refugees" and latest code, although it's clearly not well supported.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.osnews.com/story/22388

Apple discontinued their ZFS project unfortunately.  This was announced back in October and they removed the official mailing lists and repositories.

Comment: There was an unofficial ZFS port to the mac though. Do you know where it has moved to?